# IntelliJ: search and replace 'var' declarations with actual types

Tags: java, intellij-idea

**Question:** Is there a way to replace all `var` declaration with actual types in IntelliJ IDEA?

**Context:** I implemented a large feature using vars but turns out all developers in the team are against using vars and I have to rework it back to actual types.

Comment: Why they are against?

Comment: Simply replacing with `short $1 = ` and then clicking on the red error circle for a correction seems best - if that works. But you might try to revert to a java version 9 prior to var. Or keep replacing `var (\w+) = new ArrayList<(\w+)>` with `List<$2> $1 = new ArrayList<>`.

Comment: Against VAR? Send this link for them :) http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286

Comment: @JoopEggen Java can infer types as the result of method calls, e.g. `var a = foo();` The type is not necessarily included on the line, so a regex is not sophisticated enough.

Comment: @Michael yes, without version control it'll be punishment.

Comment: @JulianoMacedo the existence of a feature doesn't mean it should be used indiscriminately. [Stuart Marks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1441122/stuart-marks) sets out [style guidelines around `var`](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/amber/LVTIstyle.html): "There is a certain amount of controversy over this feature. Some welcome the concision it enables; others fear that it deprives readers of important type information, impairing readability. And both groups are right."

Comment: @AndyTurner I understood your point, and I agree with you. However, no one here said anything about "use var indiscriminately". I think that you understood in the wrong way :) I simply shared a link that can help someone to understand better about local-variable type inference, for java 10+.

Comment: @JulianoMacedo saying "Against VAR?" connotes finding it surprising that anybody could hold that viewpoint.

Comment: @AndyTurner Ok. I desire a nice day for you :)

Comment: var is awesome, much cleaner code, still strongly typed.  Tell your team to get on board LOL

Comment: @davesbrain I changed teams twice since then :) I am using vars, but I am not using Java anymore, haha

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is an inspection specifically for this:

1. Go to Code -> Analyze Code -> Run Inspection by Name... (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> by default)
2. Type enough of "Variable Type can be explicit" until you see it in the list, then select it
3. Pick the scope you want to run the inspection over.
4. In the '*Inspection Results*' dialog, click the lightbulb button labelled '*Replace 'var' with explicit type*'

You should carefully review the suggested fixes, as the inspection may well use the most specific type, e.g. `ArrayList<Foo>`, whereas it may well be more appropriate to use `List<Foo>` (there is no way for a tool to know that in all cases).

There is a complementary inspection called "Local variable type can be omitted", to replace explicit types with `var`.

Comment: I was looking for the other way around. This answer (also the question) helped a lot. Thanks

Comment: Inspection name is actually "Variable type can be explicit"